# Java create matching string with regex using known parameters

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to make a string reconstruction with parameters based on a regex pattern.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
String regex =  "(?<string>[a-z\-]+)?(/number/(?<number>\\d+))?"
```

case 1:

```
Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("string","test");
        parameters.put("number","1");

generator.generateString(regex, parameters) // returns "test/number/1"
```

case 2:

```
Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("string","test");

generator.generateString(regex, parameters) // returns "test"
```

because this group `(/number/(?<number>\\d+))?` is optional, it would still match

Maybe there's a library for it, just note that I need something that is working with regex named groups (introduced in Java7)

I could write it myself, but at least a library that could detect groups in the pattern would be a big help.
How a library like that could work:

```
Pattern2 r = Pattern2.compile("(?<string>[a-z\-]+)?(/number/(?<number>\\d+))?");
```

To find start and end character of the "string" named group
`r.start("string"); //0`

```
r.end("string"); //19
```

or to find start and end of a group by a number of a group

`r.start(2); //20`

```
r.end(2); //44
```

Comment: how this is in java? `r.end("string");`

Comment: `(?<string>[a-z\-]+)?(/number/(?<number>\\d+))?` wouldn't match any string in this format `string: test; number: 1`. At first you didn't care about colon `:` even.

Comment: Ok maybe it's a little misleading, but the  string: test; number: 1 are parameters, in a Map for example, but it's not really important. The point is not to match a regex with anything, but to create a string that would match a pattern. I will edit the question.